intl-tel-input i18n module not found
I have a vaadin 23, Spring boot 2.7.6 app. I created a typescript component for users to enter their phone numbers. I used the intl-tel-input npm package to do so.
Everything works fine except for the i18n part when I want to use the intl-tel-input provided translations.
I read the docs and they say I should import the language I want this way:
import fr from "intl-tel-input/i18n/fr";

But this gives me the following error:
TS2307: Cannot find module  intl-tel-input/i18n/fr  or its corresponding type declarations.
I can import import intlTelInput from 'intl-tel-input'; perfectly well and the component works fine. It is only the translation part that is proving challenging.
I can see the i18n folder under intl-tel-input/build/js/i18n but I can't import anything from there and it doesn't match what is said in the docs.
What am I doing wrong ?
I already tried a few different ways to import from intl-tel-input/build/js/i18n/fr (again, not the right folder according to the docs).
I tried modifying my types.d.ts to declare the intl-tel-input//i18n module but it is not working.

Looks like the Typescript definitions for intl-tel-input are broken. You'd best report this issue in their repo. As a workaround you could add @ts-ignore above your import, though you of course don't get type checks for the imported module.
